# Is "titular" the appropriate word for a song that only uses the album title in its lyrics, not title?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, word-usage

Is a song on a music album considered to be the *titular* song if it doesn't share the title of the album, but incorporates it into the lyrics? If not, is there another appropriate term for this lyrical gimmick?

Comment: "titular" just means "nominal"; it has no connection to what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlbumTitleDrop), this is known as an "album title drop".

Although I'm surprised there's not a single word for it. Maybe you can make something up like "non-eponymous".

Comment: From your link, it seems the album title is dropped into the song lyrics, hence the term.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's as close to what I'm looking for as I'll get!

Comment: I'd imagine that the album title is usually *pulled from* the song lyrics, and not *dropped into* them (unlike *title drops* in movies or TV episodes).

Comment: **Peter is 1000% correct.** It's important to note the "TV Tropes" site (glance at it) is staggeringly badly written, inaccurate and confused.  It's ridiculous to see it as helping us with this issue, so dismiss that. **A "title drop" is a very straightforward, well-known phrase in the film industry.**  (It's when the actual title of the movie, happens to work its way in to something said by one character - simply google anywhere (err, except "tv tropes") for definitions and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Adjective

1.Holding or constituting a purely formal position or title without any real authority:

> The queen is titular head of the Church of England

2.Nominally appointed to serve a diocese, abbey, or other foundation no longer in existence, and typically in fact having...

Synonyms:

nominal - titulary

Origin:

Date: 1500-1600
Language: Latin
Origin: titulus

If you are worried for being inappropriate, use *nominal* for instance.

Comment: This answer does not make clear what is a quote from a dictionary and what is original material, nor does it cite the dictionary quoted (which is always good practice, and necessary for protection from copyright/plagiarism claims).

Comment: The first two definitions are taken from the [Oxford dictionaries online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/titular) (although possibly by way of another website), and amazingly, the answer leaves out the pertinent definition: **relating to or denoted by a title:** *the work's titular song*. Nominal is not, in fact, a synonym for this definition.